# Doubt in Proof of Dirichlet Asymptotic formula for partial sum of divisor function $d(n)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am studying Analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory and I  have doubt in the proof given in the book.

Dirichlet gives two proof of formula 
1 st has error term $O(x)$  and I don't have any doubt in it.

> I have doubt in his 2nd proof where he deduces error term to be $(2C-1) x +O(\sqrt{x})$. He writes before giving the argument of Lattice Points that we take advantage of symmetry of region about $q=d$. The total number of lattice points in region is equal to twice the number below line q=d plus the number of bisecting line segments. 
>   I don't understand how apostol derives the formula  which I am mentioning in the image along with the diagram.

[image]

Can somebody please tell how to derive this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\le x} d(n)= \sum_{n\le x}\sum_{md=n}1=\sum_{md\le x}1= 2\sum_{md\le x,d<m} 1+ \sum_{d^2\le x}  1=2\sum_{d<\sqrt{x}}(\lfloor x/d\rfloor -d) + \lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$$
In the figure : 
$ \lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$ is the number of lattice point on the diagonal,

$\lfloor x/d\rfloor -d$ is the number of lattice points with abscissa $d$ and on the right side of the diagonal (the **horizontal** segment plotted in the black region)

The asymptotic is immediate from there since $\lfloor x/d\rfloor = x/d+O(1)$

Comment: I think summation d(n) on n$\leq$ x  would be equal to $\sum_{n\leq x}$  $\sum_{md \leq x } $  where d | n.I didn't understood  how you came to 1st line of your answer. Can you explain

Comment: can you please tell what's wrong with my comment?

Comment: $d(n)= \sum_{m,k,mk=n}1$

Comment: @rens can u pls answer the doubt only with the already existing formulae in the chapter and not use description of the diagram?