Alternating series of fractional parts of reciprocal integers
Define
$$ f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R};\qquad f(n):=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k \left\{ \frac{n}{k} \right\} $$
where $\{\cdot \}$ means the fractional part.
I would like to determine if this function is bounded.
I didn't get much of a feel of what was going on for prime $n$ vs composite $n.$ I did notice that $f(n)$ is large (negative) if $n=t!$ for some integer $t,$ but I'm not sure I trust wolframalpha's approximation of some of these numbers.
Interestingly, wolframalpha's graph of the partial sums look like a chaotic map/ random walk, but I'm not sure this is so relevant to my specific question.

Is it maybe easier to estimate it  as $$nH_n-\sum_k (-1)^k\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor?$$Then to total cumulative for $\lfloor n/k\rfloor =d$ is  in ${0,d,-d}.$ But not sure if that helps.

I found a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510025/limit-of-alternating-sum-of-fractional-parts?rq=1

When the cumulated value for $d$ is $\pm d$ then  the next higher non-zero accumulation is $\mp d.$

Here is a related sequence in the OEIS, but not alternating: oeis.org/A075710
